# Is it possible to weave an aspect to dynamically instantiated class?

Tags: spring, dynamic, aspectj

I use Spring and have an aspect that wraps around some class:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect{

    @Around("execution(public * com.service.MyService.doStuff(..))")
    public Object log(){
        ...
    }
}
```

and in context xml:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.bla.bla.bla.LoggingAspect"/>
```

The problem is that instances of `MyService` are created at runtime so Spring knows nothing about this class during context initialization phase. Is it possible to use aspects in this case to wrap method calls of a class instantiated using `new` (not Spring)?

Comment: What you you mean by "dynamically instantiated" - The Class is a normal class and you use new (but not spring) to create it?

Answer (score 2):

If my reading of [the Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) is correct, you do it like this (for Spring proxy-based weaving):

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(new SimplePojo());
factory.addInterface(Pojo.class);
factory.addAdvice(new RetryAdvice());

Pojo pojo = (Pojo) factory.getProxy();
```

or like this (for AspectJ-style weaving):

```
AspectJProxyFactory factory = new AspectJProxyFactory(new SimplePojo()); 
factory.addAspect(new RetryAspect());

Pojo proxy = factory.getProxy();
```

(I drive all my AOP weaving through my bean configuration so I've not needed to use this sort of thing in practice.)

Comment: The other thing you could try is to use the Spring “prototype” lifecycle for the class that you're instantiating.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only use Spring AOP to advise Spring beans (because Spring creates a proxy object behind the scenes). You'll have to use full AspectJ, or create your MyService in the Spring container. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-choosing.